# Проблема с AsyncTask в Android или как реализовать очередь действий?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Вот такой код инициализации таска

```
CoordsAnalizatorTask coordsAnalizatorTask = new CoordsAnalizatorTask();
```

Далее я выполняю его запуск с параметрами

```
coordsAnalizatorTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, new Double[]{coords_w, coodrs_l, angle});
```

По сути `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` указывает на то, что задачи будут выполняться последовательно, в чём я не сомневаюсь. Нашёл [статью](http://www.wtg.ru/products/onlinedev/011/), где есть пример и там чётко видно, что вызовы совершаются последовательно (В самом низу статьи) т.е. если я буду посылать задачи примерно так

```
coordsAnalizatorTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, new Double[]{coords_w, coodrs_l, angle});
coordsAnalizatorTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, new Double[]{coords_w, coodrs_l, angle});
```

То они обе должны быть переданы в **AsyckTask**, но выполнены они будут не параллельно, а последовательно, что мне и нужно, но выполняя такие действия мне выскакивает ошибка

```
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.miroshnichenko.mylineviewexample, PID: 21238
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.miroshnichenko.mylineviewexample/com.example.miroshnichenko.mylineviewexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:576)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.miroshnichenko.mylineviewexample.CoordinatesAnalizator.sendCoords(CoordinatesAnalizator.java:63)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.miroshnichenko.mylineviewexample.NmeaParser.addNmeaByteArray(NmeaParser.java:62)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.miroshnichenko.mylineviewexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
12-01 12:40:41.811 21238-21238/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Что как бы говорит, что я не могу юзать **AsyncTask**, пока он работает, что очень странно, т.к. в примере ясно написано, что последовательное выполнение при таком вызове должно быть и быть без ошибок.

Суть задачи такова, что есть поток, который постоянно парсит координаты и кидает их в **AsyncTask**, далее таск с ними должен последовательно работать, т.е. обрабатывать одну задачу за другой, но вот те на, такая проблема возникла. Подскажите решение проблемы или предложите альтернативу. Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: нельзя один и тот же инстанс асинктаски добавить на выполнение 2 раза. Создайте просто новый инстанс этой таски

Comment: @metalurgus Да, спасибо, я уже увидел свою ошибку. А при таком подходе задачи последовательно будут выполняться? Просто я тогда не совсем понимаю, каким образом при создании нового объекта и его запуска AsyncTask поймёт, что там уже запущен другой таск, одно дело, когда туда передаёшь все таски методом, тогда объект будет вкусе, что кто первый пришёл, того и будем выполнять, а других в очередь, а тут банально создание нового объекта, откуда он будет в курсе о выполнении другого?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK они будут выполняться последовательно на SERIAL_EXECUTORе.
к примеру есть объект X и Y и вы вызываете X.executeOnExecutor(SERIAL_EXECUTOR и Y.executeOnExecutor(SERIAL_EXECUTOR), объекты разные, а среда исполнения одна - статический Executor из класса AsyncTask

Comment: @iksuy Я так понимаю там инстант экзекутера внутри AsyncTask?

Comment: @BORSHEVIK да, все верно. Я же в своем ответе написал, не стесняйтесь смотреть исходники библиотек в таких случаях, это очень помогает для более глубинного понимания происходящего и вообще для профессионального развития :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это одна и та же задача.

```
coordsAnalizatorTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, new Double[]{coords_w, coodrs_l, angle});
```

Объект `coordsAnalizatorTask` уже работает, и вы его снова пытаетесь запустить. Нужно либо дожидаться когда данная задача отработает, либо создавать новый объект каждый раз (зависит от того, что вам нужно)

Рекомендую в таких случаях смотреть исходники библиотечных методов, которые вы используете, и в которых `Exception` вылетает. В данном случае можете поглядеть в каких случаях бросается `IllegalStateException` внутри `executeOnExecutor`

Answer (score 0):

Для последовательно выполняемых тасков я бы посмотрел в сторону IntentService

Comment: Я о нём знаю, но там есть небольшие танцы с бубнами, если необходимо получать результат от сервиса

Comment: EventBus вам в помощь!

Comment: Спасибо за либу, но на самом деле я под танцами с бубном имел ввиду биндинг